# Sun Netra 240: How to get from ALOM menu to ok prompt?

Tags: solaris, sparc

I am connected to my server using a serial connection. I am currently at the ALOM menu (as shown below. I need to get to the {ok} prompt. How do I get there from here?

FYI, One major complication: I don't have the boot password. I'm trying to reset it and install Solaris from a boot disc.

```
ALOM <ESC> Menu

f - Wait for flash download from host.
C - Copy Boot Monitor from FLASHBOAT.
j - Jump to main code (at 0x01010000).
m - Run POST Menu.
    (Do not try this after a flash update of the boot monitor!)
d - play DOOM
s - Set clock speed
e - Set external and internal console serial ports baud rate
i - Set internal control serial port baud rate
t - Toggle 'OK' flag
R - Reset SC
b,h,w - Read byte/halfword/word
B,H,W - Write byte/halfword/word
r - Return to bootmon
Your selection:
```

Answer (score 1):

Press the keys:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Function (Fn)</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (which should be "pause") and a message should appear on screen.

Do this AFTER all the probing, and give it a try to understand when it's the right time to give those key strokes.

I'm using SecureCRT.

```
SC Alert: SC Request to send Break to host.
SC Alert: SC Request to send Break to host.
Probing system devices

Starting RTC ..
Probing memory
Probing I/O buses

Netra 240, Keyboard Present
Copyright 2010 Sun Microsystems, ...




Running diagnostic script obdiag/normal

Testing /pci@1e,600000/ide@d
...


Initializing  1024MB of memory at addr                 0 /            
SC Alert: SC Request to send Break to host.

Type  'go' to resume
{1} ok
```